# nodejs - Which "this" is this?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So this is an awkward question to ask, but I'm learning NodeJS and I have a question. In Java when I call a method from an object, the `this` instance remains the same (as in this example).

```
private Test inst;
public Test() {
    inst = this;
    this.myFunction();
}

private void myFunction() {
    System.out.println(inst == this);
}
```

This returns true (in theory, that's code off the top of my head). However, in NodeJS when I attempt to do something similar it fails.

```
var MyObject = function () {
    this.other = new OtherObject();
    this.other.on("error", this.onError);
    console.log(this); //This returns the MyObject object
}

MyObject.prototype.onError = function (e) {
    console.log(this); //This returns the OtherObject object, where I thought it would return the MyObject object.
}
```

My question is why is this so, and if this is being done incorrectly on my part, how may I correctly reference other variables in the MyObject instance from the onError method?

Comment: AFAIK, `this` in javascript is very tricky. In case of calling it in function, it points to the caller, not the object where is the function defined.

Comment: @walther— *this* in javascript is not tricky at all. It's set by the call, or the use of *bind*, that's it. While it is different to other languages, it's not really difficult to understand.

Comment: @RobG, that's precisely the tricky part - other languages do it differently and it confuses the hell out of some developers. If it was really that clear, a question like this would never arise (and this is not the first, nor last time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript "methods" are just functions that part of an object.

If you do

```
var obj = new MyObject();
obj.onError();
```

The this in onError will be the obj object (because it is the object it is invoked from)

Instead in you case you are passing this.onError to the EventEmitter it will call that function with the EventEmitter (OtherObject) as this.

To avoid that problem use an anonimous function.

```
var MyObject = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.other = new OtherObject();
    this.other.on("error", function (e) { self.onError(e); });
}
```

In this way you are binding this back to the object you expect

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so well, and for the great usage example!

Comment: For an even cleaner solution use the bind method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @RobG it was a semplification. By the way fixed

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way - you can use bind function.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var MyObject = function () {
    this.other = new EventEmitter();
    this.other.on("error", this.onError.bind(this));
    console.log(1, this instanceof MyObject); // 1, true
};

MyObject.prototype.onError = function (e) {
    console.log(2, this instanceof MyObject); // 2, true
};

MyObject.prototype.callError = function (e) {
    console.log(3, this instanceof MyObject); // 3, true
    this.other.emit('error', e);
};

var mo = new MyObject();

mo.callError(new Error(1));
```

[Demo](http://code.runnable.com/VZUJl54xlCYFByL2/bind-in-node-js-for-hello-world)